# Android:the button followed the cursor

Tags: android, button

How can I change the button's positon with my cursor moving.
I mean how to let the button follow the cursor as I move the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to implement on touch listener.

```
new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private float downX = 0;
            private float downY = 0;
```

`@Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
                    this.downX = motionEvent.getX();
                    this.downY = motionEvent.getY();
                    break;


                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    final View btn= layout.findViewById(R.id.button);
                    currentView.layout(newLeft,
                            newTop, newRight,
                            newBottom));
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }`

Comment: Kalabin : Is this right:'code''mSwitchBtn = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.status_bar,null).findViewById(R.id.lock_switch_button);
        mSwitchBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
         private int x;
         private int y;
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {switch(event.getAction()){
  case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
   x = (int)event.getX();
   y = (int)event.getY();
     break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
     mSwitchBtn.layout(x,y,mSwitchBtn.getWidth()+x,mSwitchBtn.getHeight()+y);
mSwitchBtn.invalidate();
}
return true;
}      
});''code'

Comment: @Zhao-Rocky it seems right, but i'm not sure about `mSwitchBtn.getHeight()` and `mSwitchBtn.getWidth()` methods - it can returns 0.

You can use \` for one line of code and \<pre\> for posting pre-formatted text